# Uninstall and reinstall mysql server in Lenny Debian (broken installation)

Tags: mysql, lenny

I removed MySQL server and tried to install it once again on my system Lenny Debian

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

During the installation everything loaded OK until the connexion test phase that fails and the installation is stopped. In the error log file I found the next:

```
Trying to start service mysql... done
 Trying to establish test connection... /usr/bin/mysql: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file $
/usr/bin/mysql: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

With `ldd /usr/bin/mysql` I got the following result:

```
/usr/bin/mysql: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/bin/mysql)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff170ea000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe39cfab000)
        libreadline.so.6 => not found
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe39cd94000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe39cb90000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe39c90d000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe39c5ba000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe39d1c7000)
```

How to install this missing library in order to restart the MySQL server installation?

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i readline`?  Or some more or less minor variant on the theme — you may need to download the correct `.deb` file first and then specify that to `dpkg`.  Or there may be a tool that sits above `dpkg` that does the fetch for you.

Comment: The command `sudo dpkg -i readline` gave me `dpkg: error processing readline (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 readline`  Could  you please explain more how to download the correct `.deb`

Comment: No; I haven't used Debian, which is one of the reasons I gave you a comment rather than an answer.  I've used Ubuntu, where the equivalent is `sudo apt-get readline`, and I reserve the right to need version information attached to the name, or specified somehow. I recommend reading the manual, or checking online for how to use `dpkg` (I found its name after searching on Google for 'debian package installer'; try 'debian install readline'). It's likely that this question more properly belongs on SuperUser or ServerFault, but I'm doing my best to point you in approximately the correct direction.

Comment: The package name on Debian AND Ubuntu is libreadline6. For both of them the command will be "apt-get install libreadline6"